# Replacement, for 'I argue that.....'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I don't want to use an 'I', would someone be able to help me think of an alternative.

Comment: how about "We" instead of "I"?

Comment: You can make it impersonal.  "It can be argued that..."

Comment: ... or informal: "You morons should at least consider the possibility that ..." Just kidding.

Comment: Leave "I argue that" out altogether and simply state it as fact.

Answer (score 2):

Phrases that could replace this are:

- In response
- One might argue...
- It could be said/argued...